# Bash script to get API endpoints from spring-boot projects

Tags: bash, shell, api

I am writing a bash script to get API endpoints from a java file (maven spring-boot project).

```
echo "$(grep -E '@RequestMapping' userAPI.java)"
```

The above line extracted this following result:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/{userId}", produces = { "application/json" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/{userId}/applications", produces = { "application/json" }, 
                method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

My final goal is to get the two endpoints into two variables

```
var1 = "GET /users/{userId}"
var2 = "GET /users/{userId}/applications"
```

Please advise what to do next based on the above result? Thanks. I am thinking to use grep and sed, or so on.

As a simpler case, how can I just get the endpoints without verb into two variables, i.e,

```
var1 = "/users/{userId}"
var2 = "/users/{userId}/applications"
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, do you have any XML configuration files that you can use instead? It sounds weird to me that you have to parse a file that way to extract values. Another suggestion, please excuse me that I am not a top expert at spring-boot, just add a tag spring-boot to the question. This way it could be viewed by more specialists at the subject.

Comment: @KrassiEm many thanks, I've resolved the issue. In my mind, this is the only place I can find both  http verb and the associated endpoint, maybe spring-boot is different from other projects. But configuration file is normally the place to get such information, that's true.